# sencha templating in mvc pattern

Tags: android, iphone, templates, extjs

The code below is for main view i.e main.js , where i have called intro.js i.e another view. Now i am unable to render the data on the template . I am new to sencha , i think i messed up something on declaration

```
Ext.define("casta.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    apitoken:'NULL',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'casta.view.Intro'

    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'top',

        items: [


                { title:'Intro',
                   xclass: 'casta.view.Intro' ,
                   iconCls:'user'
                 }

                 ]
    }
});
```

intro.js is as below. I think while declaring the variable I messed up some thing . It is showing blank screen

```
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
//alias: 'widget.currentDate', //this makes it xtype 'currentDate'
//store: 'CurrentDateStore',


initComponent: function(){
    planetEarth = { name: "Earth", mass: 1.00 };

    tpl = new Ext.Template(['<tpl for".">', '<p> {name} </p>', '</tpl>'].join(''));
    tpl.compile();
    //this.callParent(arguments);

},
html:tpl.apply(planetEarth)
});
```

below is the console log

```
tpl is not defined
```

[Break On This Error]

```
html:tpl.apply(planetEarth)
```

Comment: are you cheeking it on chrome ? if yes than can you provide the log of console?

Comment: yes, please check the updated question'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initComponent is going to be called at some time after the html var is set. instead define your tpl like so:

```
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    tpl: '<p> {name} </p>',
    initComponent: function(){
        //Be sure to use the var keyword for planet earth, otherwise its declared as a global variable
        var planetEarth = { name: "Earth", mass: 1.00 };
        this.setHtml(this.getTpl().apply(planetEarth));
    }
});
```

This will work, following your pattern, but you probably want to define that component more like so:

```
Ext.define('casta.view.Intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    tpl: '<p> {name} </p>'
});
```

Then instantiate it like:

```
Ext.define("casta.view.Main", {
    extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    apitoken : 'NULL',
    requires : ['Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.Video', 'casta.view.Intro'],
    config : {
        tabBarPosition : 'top',
        items : [{
            xclass : 'casta.view.Intro',
            title : 'Intro',
            iconCls : 'user',
            data: {name: "Earth", mass: 1.00 }
            }]
    }
});
```